# I'm trying to find a pattern for sql regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

My string is `prefvalue:CEROTG`, I want to match `prefvalue:` but I want to print `CEROTG` only

Comment: `regexp_substr(col, 'prefvalue:([[:alnum:]_]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Regex for that would be `prefvalue:(\S+)` , but I am uncertain about where this value comes from. If it's stored in column (cell), this hugely depends on which RDBMS you are using. Some doesn't support regex in queries.

Explanation of pattern:

`prefvalue:` - match `prefvalue:` literally

`(...)` - capturing group

`\S+` - match one ore more of any characters, other than whitespace

To return from pattern what you need, just refernce first capturing group with `\1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s8vdKM/1)

**EDIT**

Additionally you can add boundaries, to make sure you want match it as substring of some longer string: `^prefvalue:(\S+)$`

`^` - matches beginning of a string

`$` - matches end of string

[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bc0e6/8)

Comment: I'm using oracle rdbms

Comment: @niku as far as I know it supports regex so you can try my pattern in query :) `REGEXP_REPLACE` is method for you, it accepts replacing with capturing groups as well.

Comment: I tried this method it fetched the other two fields 
prefgroup:cdi_globals
prefentry:imagerepository

Comment: @niku And isn't it what you want? Do you want only `perfvalue:SOMETHING` which is not followed by anything?

Comment: @niku See my edit.

Comment: SELECT Regexp_substr(entry_data,'', 1, 1, 'i') AS VALUE_STR,
'CPDI_ACTIVE_STORAGE_PATH' AS STAT_NAME
FROM   v500.prefdir_entrydata 
WHERE  dist_name_short = 
'prefentry=imagerepository,prefgroup=cdi_globals,prefgroup=component,prefgroup=system,prefcontext=default,prefroot=prefroot'

Comment: can you look into this query and help me once

Comment: my regex was 'prefvalue:[A-Z]* and it would fetch me value like this prefvalue:CEROTG

Comment: I just want CEROTG to be selected

Comment: @niku See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bc0e6/8

Comment: Much appreciated 
prefgroup:orderprofileomview
prefentry:columnwidths I'm getting these columns

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression. You can use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( your_column, 11 ) AS prefvalue
FROM   table_name
WHERE  your_column LIKE 'prefvalue:%';
```

If you has some test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( your_column ) AS
SELECT 'prefvalue:CEROTG'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'prefvalue:ABCD'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'othervalue:NOTTHIS' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> | PREFVALUE |
> | :-------- |
> | CEROTG    |
> | ABCD      |
> ```

and, if you just want the `CEROTG` rows:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( your_column, 11 ) AS prefvalue
FROM   table_name
WHERE  your_column = 'prefvalue:CEROTG';
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | PREFVALUE |
> | :-------- |
> | CEROTG    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4612deceee93a95a20ac8a8995b5579f)*